# iis express package as Xammp

Tags: mysql, sql, iis-express

I have a rather general question. I've decided to go with ASP.NET MVC for my next intranet web app, mainly for learning purposes. The truth is that, after years of PHP programming I've got spoiled by Xammp which covers every developer need (php+MySql). Normally I download and drop Xammp on any machine and it is just works. In my case I have to use Windows Server 2003 which runs IIS6.0 and it can't be upgraded (according to MS).

I was hoping to find something similar to Xampp (development / production package) for ASP.NET but it seems that there is none :( I saw some developers using IIS Express + SQLCE on WinServer2003, but I am not sure about database servers ( eg. SQL, SQL Express etc). ... Actually this is my question what do you use on old servers? Can we use IIS Express for production puroposes? Limitations?

Comment: You can install XAMPP on Windows Server 2003 in C:\xampp directory, then can use port forwarding to load the site.
You may need to change httpd.conf

Comment: I now that already because currently I am running intranet web app based on Drupal on Windows Server 2003. I would like to use latest ASP.NET MVC + SQL express or MySQL stack  instead

Comment: You can try http://windows.php.net/ it is PHP in IIS environment

Comment: Maybe I am not clear, in what I am asking. I would like to move away from PHP. I would like to use latest ASP.NET MVC on Windows Server2003.

Comment: I would suggest you to check http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx and also google "ASP.net MVC"

Comment: Thanks, I am hoping to find more straitforword solution, meaning Why should I hack something and not just drop in IIS express and run it as a service.